# using CSS: lang() selector to toggle a divs visibility

Tags: html, css, lang

Well it's not working, maybe it just doesn't.  I want to show a  container based on the browsers language.

The intial setting for all the divs is vanished.
I've tried using the property display: none, and also visibility: hidden, to no avail.  The language selector won't override the initial setting.

```
 .france-box, .german-box, .dutch-box, .italy-box { display: none }

 .france-box :lang(fr) { display: flex }
 .german-box :lang(de) { display: flex; }
 .dutch-box :lang(nl) { display: flex; }
 .italy-box :lang(en) { display: flex; }
```

It seems to work the other way, if the language is valid I can hide divs, but not show them.

Any ideas how to do this using, ideally, just css.  I want a lean solution.

Comment: Please add your HTML as well.

Comment: remove the spaces between .frace-box :lang(fr) and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here:

## Changing the display of an element descended from `display: none` does nothing

The descendant combinator between the class selector and the lang pseudo-class selector mean that only elements descended from elements which are `display: none` (from line 1) will be targetted.

Here is a simplified example:

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

div span {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div><span>...</span></div>
```

Since the `div` is `display: none`, it doesn't matter what the `span` is. It won't be shown because it is in the `div`.

---

## The `:lang:` pseudo-class doesn't do what you think it does

It represents the language the **element** is written in. It has nothing to do with the configuration of the browser (i.e. nothing to do with the language the browser UI is in and nothing to do with the user's language preferences).

```css
:lang(en) { background: pink; }
:lang(fr) { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<p lang="en">This is English</p>
<p lang="fr">C'est français</p>
```

---

CSS has no mechanism for detecting the user's language.

You can use server-side code to examine the `Accept-Lang` request header sent by the browser and provide a different document based on the user's preferences.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks Quentin, you're right I misunderstood.  Very thorough answer vote for Quentin folks!

Comment: There are no descending elements, does not apply the supposed first problem. My concern would be changing selector rules when changing display attribute. If .france-box is told to be display:none, .france-box should be the one changed to display:flex.

Comment: @LluísTurróCutiller — "There are no descending elements" — The code in the question applies `display: none` to `.france-box` and `display: flex` to `.france-box :lang(fr)`. That's a descendant combinator between `.france-box` and `:lang(fr)`. The fact they are different elements is **the exactly problem** I discuss in this answer.